# GSON object serialization breaks when I add a Handler object in my model class

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I have a POJO in Android, which is serialized from a server's JSON response with GSON, without any problem.

```
public ExampleClass implements Serializable {
    @Expose 
    String someProperty;
}
```

For some reason, I would like to store a Handler object in my class, like:

```
public ExampleClass implements Serializable {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Expose 
    String someProperty;
}
```

After adding this extra line, the serialization breaks with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public com.example.android.ExampleClass() with no args
```

I've tried adding a no-args constructor for my class, no success.
I've tried making the Handler object transient, but still no success.

---

UPDATE:

So, I've found the solution. The problem here is that the Handler object is initialized before finishing the serialization of the object.

So this isn't breaking the serialization:

```
public ExampleClass implements Serializable {

    private Handler handler;

    @Expose 
    String someProperty;
}
```

But where to initialize it? If I try to do it in the no-args constructor, the serialization breaks again:

```
public ExampleClass implements Serializable {

    private Handler handler;

    @Expose 
    String someProperty;

    public ExampleClass() {
        handler = new Handler(); // breaks serialization 
    }
}
```

If I initialize it later when the serialization finished, it works:

```
public ExampleClass implements Serializable {

    private Handler handler;

    @Expose 
    String someProperty;

    public void functionCalledInTheFuture() {
        handler = new Handler(); // works
    }
}
```

I am not completely understanding this, so if somebody can explain it to me, please don't hesitate! :)

Comment: Not sure why you need handler there, but this should help use `transient` keyword to exclude it from serialization: `private transient Handler handler = new Handler();`

Comment: Thanks @Mykhailo for your answer, I wrote at the end of the question that adding the transient keyword didn't help

Comment: oops didn't notice. Have you tried to add public constructor `public ExampleClass() { }` ?

Comment: Yep, I wrote this as well, but I've found the solution, I am posting an answer for the question

Comment: I have updated the question with a solution

Comment: This is a nice workaround! Because the handler is not initialized in c'tor (implicit or explicit) the serialization mechanism skip it when calling the c'tor. Nice! I do however still think that getting the handler out of there would be better

Comment: Thanks @ymz it is more clear now! I am accepting your answer because it answers the original question. About the Handler: I want to make repetitive calls (polling) with the help of it and a Runnable, but yes, probably I can find some other place to do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... this is interesting because `transient` keyword should do the trick. But.. this is only a shortcut to a common use-case. It may not work if the library or code that handle the serialization process ignores it.

There is a good article, that covers serialization topic in JAVA ([read this](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-exclude-fields-serialization)). **In short**: you may customize `ExclusionStrategy` to add a dedicated behavior to your class

**Code highlights:**

```
ExclusionStrategy strategy = new ExclusionStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes field) {
        if (field.getDeclaringClass() == MyClass.class && field.getName().equals("other")) {
            return true;
        }
        if (field.getDeclaringClass() == MySubClass.class && field.getName().equals("otherVerboseInfo")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
};

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(strategy)
  .create();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(source);

assertEquals(expectedResult, jsonString);
```

Yes.. this is probably an overkill to your problem, but it should work for all use cases

Comment: Thank you @ymz, I have found a solution to my problem and updated my question, please take a look at it, maybe you understand what's happening here